# "1 unresolved externals" C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've checked the connections between all of my files, as well as Class and Function definitions, but every time I try to run my program it stops me and tells me that it has "1 unresolved externals".

The program is supposed to open up multiple files (A "student" file, and a "grades" file), read from them, and then use a "query file" to look through the data, find the students asked for in the query file, and print it to a new file. Confusing? Yes.

Still, I'm pretty close to a solution, but because I'm using Visual Studio it won't even let me run the program until I find and put an end to the "1 unresolved externals". It won't even tell me where the error is. I'm fairly new to C++, and no matter how hard I search, I can't seem to remedy the issue.

Here's my Main Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){



    //Request a file to read from, and open it (I haven't declared the files yet, don't worry about that)
    ifstream input_file;
    string studentfile = "";
    string gradefile = "";
    string queryfile = "";


    //Create a Map for the Students
    map<string, Student *> student_map;

    //Open the Student file and load it in
    cout << "Loading \"" << studentfile << "\"... " <<endl;
    input_file.open(studentfile);

    //Look for:
    string id_number;
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;

    //Boolean value to check for duplicate students
    bool duplicate = false;

    //Check to see if the Student File is empty
    if (!input_file.eof()){ 

        while (input_file.good()){
            //Get the ID Number
            input_file.get();
            getline (input_file, id_number);

            //Sort through and make sure there are no duplicate students
            for (map<string, Student *>::iterator counter = student_map.begin(); counter != student_map.end(); counter ++){
                if (counter->first == id_number ){
                    duplicate = true;
                    counter = student_map.end();
                }
            }

            if (duplicate != true){
                //Get the name
                input_file.get();
                getline (input_file, name);

                //Get the Address
                input_file.get();
                getline (input_file, address);

                //Get the Phone Number
                input_file.get();
                getline (input_file, phone);

                //Create a new student                                                          
                Student * newStudent = new Student (id_number, name, address, phone);

                //Add it to the map (referenced by the ID number)
                student_map[id_number] = newStudent;
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
    input_file.close();

    //Open the Grades file and load it in
    cout << "Loading \"" << gradefile << "\"... " <<endl;
    input_file.open(gradefile);

    //Look for (id_number already defined):
    string course;
    string grade;

    if (!input_file.eof()){

        while (input_file >> course >> id_number >> grade){
            //Find the student referenced
            Student* current_student = student_map[id_number];
            //Calculate their grade points and add them to their grade point vector
            current_student ->add_grade_points(current_student ->check_grade_points(grade));
        }
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
    input_file.close();

    //Open the Query file and load it in
    cout << "Loading \"" << queryfile << "\"... " << endl;
    input_file.open(queryfile);

    if (!input_file.eof()){

        //Write to
        ofstream output_file ("report.txt");

        //No need to "Look for" anything, id_number alread defined

        //If the file is open, write to it
        if (output_file.is_open())
        {
            while (input_file >> id_number)
            {
                //Print the ID Number (With four spaces)
                output_file << id_number << "    ";

                //Print out the GPA (With four spaces)
                Student* current_student = student_map[id_number];
                output_file << current_student->get_gpa() << "    ";

                //Print out the student's name (Then end that line)
                output_file << current_student->get_name() << endl;
            }
        }
        input_file.close();
        output_file.close();
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "File Printed.";

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my "Student" Class (Header File):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student (string _id_number, string _name, string _address, string _phone);

    void add_grade_points (double grade_points);
    double check_grade_points (string grade);

    double get_gpa () const;
    string get_name () const;

private:
    string id_number;
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;

    vector <double> grade_points;
};
```

And finally, my class functions:

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student (string _id_number, string _name, string _address, string _phone){
    id_number = _id_number;
    name = _name;
    address = _address;
    phone = _phone;
}

void Student::add_grade_points (double new_grade_point){
    grade_points.push_back(new_grade_point);
}

double Student::check_grade_points (string grade) {
    if (grade == "A")
        return 4.0;
    else if (grade == "A-")
        return 3.7;
    else if (grade == "B+")
        return 3.4;
    else if (grade == "B")
        return 3.0;
    else if (grade == "B-")
        return 2.7;
    else if (grade == "C+")
        return 2.4;
    else if (grade == "C")
        return 2.0;
    else if (grade == "C-")
        return 1.7;
    else if (grade == "D+")
        return 1.4;
    else if (grade == "D")
        return 1.0;
    else if (grade == "D-")
        return 0.7;
    else
        return 0.0;
}

double Student::get_gpa() const{
    //Add up all of the grade points
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < grade_points.size(); i++) {
        total = total + grade_points[i];
    }

    //Calculate the Grade Point Average
    double gpa = total/grade_points.size();

    return gpa;
}

string Student::get_name() const{
    return name;
}
```

Any help would be so amazing!

EDIT: Here's the error message that comes up:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CS235 Project 1\Debug\CS235 Project 1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Which function is it that's unresolved? In other words, **what is the exact error message** that you get?

Comment: I think you are trying to compile console application as Windows GUI application. Linker expects `WinMain`, not `main`. Check your project settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to compile a program with the standard entry point (int main()) as a windows GUI application, and Windows GUI applications require

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow)
```

Instead.

Changing your entry point to this won't help you though, as you're trying to compile (what's called in the Visual Studio world) a 'console program'. When you set up the project, there would have been an option to create a console project. You can scrap the one you've got and create a new console project to paste your code into for an easy fix. If you're really attached to your current project though, you can fix it.

In the project settings:
Under Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor, change the _WINDOWS; string in the Preprocessor definitions to _CONSOLE;
and under Configuration Properties > Linker > System, change the SubSystem to Console.

Answer (score 2):

That's a linker error.  You are calling a function and when it come's time to link the program together, the linker can't find the function to link.

You are probably missing a library or source file.